# What should I do if I believe a question on Stackoverflow.com belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion

The question in question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873727/mounting-a-network-share-in-fedora-not-as-root

The obvious way is to suggest to close it because of off-topic, but there is no option to point it to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

There is already a suggestion to migrate it to superuser.com but I don't think it belong there.

Comment: I dunno, I think it'd be on topic on either site.  Super User does have a pocket of \*nix users on it, and [there are questions about mounting a drive via network](http://superuser.com/search?q=mount+network+%5Blinux%5D), so I don't think it'd be *rejected* there.

Comment: You vote to close it as off topic. If you'd like to suggest the poster ask it elsewhere, use a custom close reason and suggest the alternate site.

Comment: Only suggest another site iff you are active there and really understand it's scope. Also, don't suggest simply re-asking if the question isn't of acceptable quality.

Comment: Why isn't the Unix site offered as one of the "other sites" that a question belongs on ? I follow the `systemd` tag across all SE sites. The most common place I find `systemd` questions being asked is on StackExchange, but I have never found one to be on topic there. They are always a better fit for the Unix and Linux site, Server Fault or Ask Ubuntu.